# Is "I know what times your breaks are" grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

Suppose you need to call someone who's in college, and they get 3-4 breaks between classes on a regular college day. And you say

> I know what times your breaks are, I'll call you while you're on one of those breaks.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct?

Would it be better if I had used **when your breaks are...**, instead of what times? Do we use time even when talking about different times? I ask this because, we're talking about how the person gets 3-4 breaks at different times.

I read in some grammar book how it's okay to leave out the "at" when constructing sentences like the one I've used, when having an informal conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is correct but feels stilted (the sort of overly complex thing a foreign speaker would construct).

A more natural phrase would be:

> "I know when you are on break, I'll call you during one of them."

or:

> "I know when your breaks are, I'll call you then"

Or take the first half of one (up to the comma) and the second half of the other (after the comma) and you get two more sentences that sound equally English.